# formatting form data / iterating through dynamically created fieldsets

Tags: jquery, forms, api

Problem: I don't know how to accomplish formatting the form data according to the needs of the API.

Question: I'm asking for your help :)

HTML:

```
<form id="donation">
     <fieldset>
          <ul>
               <li>
                    <input type="hidden" name="method" value="submitDonations" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="donor" value="Fred" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="donor_city" value="Nashville" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="donor_state" value="TN" />
                    <select name="donate_country">
                         <option value="choose_one">Choose One</option>
                         <option value="africa">Africa</option>
                         <option value="usa">USA</option>
                         <option value="china">China</option>
                    </select>
               </li>
               <li>
                    <label for="apples">Apples: </label>
                    <input type="number" name="apples" />
                    <label for="bananas">Bananas: </label>
                    <input type="number" name="bananas" />
                    <label for="pears">Pears: </label>
                    <input type="number" name="pears" />
               </li>
               <li>
                    <button>Donate</button>
               </li>
          </ul>
     </fieldset>
</form>
```

javaScript/jQuery

```
$('#donation').delegate('select', 'change', function(event) {
    var self = $(event.target),
    insertHere = $(self).parents('fieldset');
    $('#donation')
        .find('fieldset')
        .first()
        .clone()
        .insertAfter($(insertHere));
});

$('#donation').delegate('button', 'click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#donation').find('fieldset').each(function() {
        //serializeArray() or something to go here but i can't figure it out
    });
});
```

I need the final array to be submitted to look like this/be in this format:
method=submitDonations&donor=Fred&donor_city=Nashville&donor_state=TN&donations=[{donate_country:africa, apples:500, bananas:300, pears:200}, {donate_country:use, apples:300, bananas:150, pears:400}, {donate_country:china, apples:400, bananas:320, pears:450}]

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully and finally.... I figured it out. Hopefully this will help someone else:

```
$('#donation').delegate('button', 'click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var FORMDATA = {
    method: $('#donation').find('input[name=method]').val(),
    donor: $('#donation').find('input[name=donor]').val(),
    donor_city: $('#donation').find('input[name=donor_city]').val(),
    donor_state: $('#donation').find('input[name=donor_state]').val()
};
FORMDATA.donations = [];
var fieldsets = $('#donation').find('fieldset');
for(var f = 0; f < fieldsets.length - 1; f++) {
    var fieldset = $(fieldsets[f]);
    var inputs = fieldset.find(':input');
    var data = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        data[$(inputs[i]).attr('name')] = $(inputs[i]).val();
    }
    FORMDATA.donations.push(data);
}
$.get('url/', JSON.stringify(FORMDATA), function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    if (//Errors) {
        //handle errors
    }
    //do stuff with returnObject
});
```